# Powershell script completes but exits with error code 1

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

```
$myValue= (.\command.exe arguments | select -first 1)
```

I run the above code in my Azure Devops pipeline,
`$myValue` contains the value I'm expecting, but I get:

```
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

returned once my task completes... Does anyone have any idea why? I don't know if this is a syntax problem, or if my `command.exe` does something strange to affect the exit code.

Comment: Are you sure that `.\command.exe arguments` doesn't cause an error? move it to a `try{ ... } catch { Write-Error $_ }` block to see what happens

Comment: I don't see you doing `exit 0` anywhere in your snippet.

Comment: @Moerwald [tag:powershell]'s exception handling is *exceptionally* funky with external executables.  That won't accomplish anything.

Comment: can you share you whole script?

Comment: thanks - all useful comments. Sorry I couldn't share the full code, but thanks for giving useful feedback given the limited info - guess it is just powershell being buggy as I tried the `try catch` loop and my `.exe` runs fine

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 's suggestion of adding `exit 0` at the end of the script worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the whole script I will guess that this is due to a [known issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9185) with Powershell: `Select -First` populates the ErrorVariable even on success. It's reproducible with this code:

```
PS > 1..2 | Select -First 2 -ErrorVariable X; $X | select *
 1
 2

RequestingCommandProcessor : Select-Object
 Message : System error.
 Data : {}
 InnerException :
 TargetSite : Void ProcessRecord()
 StackTrace : at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand.ProcessRecord()
 at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
 HelpLink :
 Source : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility
 HResult : -2146233087
```

You can ignore any errors with `$Error.HResult -eq -2146233087` as a workaround.

Comment: Github indicates it was fixed in [Powershell 7.0.0 Preview 6](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.0.0-preview.6) as Issue 10840.

Answer (score 5):

Putting this at the end of my script prevented the error message:

> exit 0

Credit to Maximilian Burszley's comment in the comments